# The probability of choosing a neighbor number

Tags: probability

Bob picks a random number between 1-n.
What is the probability that Alice will guess neighbor number (x-1 or x+1)?
I thought of that $\frac{\left|A\right|}{\:\left|\Omega\right|}=\frac{2}{n}$
But I know this is not true,the answer is $\frac{2(n-1)}{n^2}$
i would love an explanation of where I am wrong, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Alice and Bob are choosing integers between $1$ and $n$ inclusive. While numbers from $2$ to $n-2$ have two neighbors each, numbers at the end, $1$ and $n$ have only one neighbor.

Considering this, required probability should be
$$\frac{2}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n-2}{n}\cdot \frac{2}{n}$$

Comment: Just to be sure I understood,$\frac{2}{n}$-->because we have 2 numbers with one ,neighbor(the numbers Bob chooses),
$\frac{1}{n}$-->1=the neighbor that matches the numbers,
$\frac{n-2}{n}$-->n-2 =Numbers with 2 neighbors,
$\frac{2}{n}$---->2 Because Bob has 2 options to choose neighbors number.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I arranged it as much as I could
Thank you :)